# One Google Apps Script referenced by many documents

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a script through Google Apps Script that resides in a Google Document. I use that document as a template object, which is then copied into many Google Documents where I use those script functions.

Problem is, whenever I edit that Master Script, all the child documents have an outdated script that must be updated manually.

Is there a way to have a base master script file that I can reference in the template, and thus in all the child documents from that template? Seems like the only ways to do this are to create an Add-On, but that wouldn't seem to resolve the need for constant updating of the script.

Comment: Libraries I think will work for you- however my understanding is they are rather slow. Add-ons seem to be the way to go.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries

Comment: @OblongMedulla if I were to publish on Add-On, would I have to republish that Add-On every time I updated the Master Script?

Answer (score -1):

[Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) do provide auto-update functionality. I'd go down that route. Additionally, you can choose to only publish to yourself if you wish.

As for your question about republishing, you can update your published add-ons.