# What are the steps to share a script with multiple worksheets through gsuite?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

**What I want to do within my gsuite account**:

> To (dynamically) associate a script with multiple sheets so I can maintain their common code in one file.  (e.g. populate a custom menu with options that display when that spreadsheet opens.)

**What I've tried**:

- created a script using the script editor at https://script.google.com , but was unable to associate the script with a sheet
- loading the externally created script through the script editor's "File > open" option
- creating a script directly from a sheet using the script editor option from the sheet's menu but found no option to share it
- publishing the script, but it seems like this makes the script accessible to the general public
- I've read about [container bound scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), but I find the documentation unclear and am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Related: [Distribute Google Apps Script and push updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16997274/1595451)

Comment: Related: [Google Spreadsheet Scripts shared across spreadsheets (not libraries)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14473368/1595451)

Comment: Related: [One Google Apps Script referenced by many documents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43479038/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

your first idea was a good one:

> created a script using the script editor at https://script.google.com , but was unable to associate the script with a sheet

From a script, you can edit multiple sheets using their IDs. For example:

```
// this function edits two sheets at once
function editBothCells() {

  // assigns a variable to a spreadsheet
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1CMLVG3Wnk4C-Ck0j7YKY_vgZZNj58mip_VRNUdrjpy8");
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kxC_0AwCwapVWG5grRNBLSHYhKpcVOHbrXTZdG9fOc4");

  // runs a function on both spreadsheets
  boldenA4(ss1,ss2);
}

// this function takes cell A4 and makes it bold for all arguments
function boldenA4(spreadsheet1, spreadsheet2, and_so_on){

  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    arguments[i].getSheets()[0]
    .getRange("A4")
    .setValue("hello stackoverflow") // could be any string 
    .setFontWeight("bold"); 
  }
}
```

Below are the links to both sheets and the script:

- [stackoverflow Test sheet 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CMLVG3Wnk4C-Ck0j7YKY_vgZZNj58mip_VRNUdrjpy8/edit#gid=0)  - feel free to edit it
- [stackoverflow Test sheet 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kxC_0AwCwapVWG5grRNBLSHYhKpcVOHbrXTZdG9fOc4/edit#gid=0) - feel free to edit
- [the script that can edit them](https://script.google.com/d/1b0eggxZ8IGOhhtCGym0TJ5x8aL7azsdL1rr3m93XCOc1M-WjDkSVDt8u/edit?usp=sharing) - feel free to run it.

Comment: I had to change my question because this answers what I asked, but I failed to be specific about what I meant! :)  I am hoping to create a menu with common functions that are meant to operate on any sheet opened in a particular folder.